# I made a fluctuating circuit that controls an LED to be on or off, How does it work?

Tags: transistors, capacitor, resistors

I have this circuit, 
The two ends represent the positive and negative terminals of the battery. 
Values

```
R6-4.7K
R1-470K
R2-470K
R3-4.7K
C1-.1 uf
C2-.1 uf
```

All transistors are NPN. Can someone please explain how this circuit causes fluctuations?I have no idea whats going on here. please help

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your diagram is too small and fuzzy to read the text.  But the two cross-connected transistors in the center form an **astable** multi-vibrator circuit. Essentially a low-frequency, square-wave oscillator.

The transistor in the lower left corner forms a driver which controls power to the LED in the lower right corner.

**Corrected:** Thank you Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams for pointing out that it is an A-stable multi-vibrator (one with no stable state, it continuously oscillates)

Comment: Astable. "Bi-stable" is a flip-flop.